# Match and Replace a regular expression patteren

Tags: c#, regex

I want to validate a regular expression pattern and replace its value with my dynamic value

the pattern is

```
$[ABCD]$test$[xyz]$
```

first i have to parse and validate such pattern and if its fine Replace the value "ABCD" and "xyz" with my dynamic value in c#.net

please help

Comment: How are you going to use the resultant regular expression?

Comment: I am going to use this expression with javascript to validate a input

Comment: Okay, sorry for the questions but I don't understand why you'd want to do this. Is the regular expression being entered into you app by a user? Is this why you want to validate the regex first? You could find that your dynamic value affects the operation of the regex, i.e. if it contains reserved characters, that's something to also consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right, you just want to replace ABCD and xyz with some values that you may hand to the methode where you check the expression.

Try this code

```
        string value1 = "firstValue";
        string value2 = "secondValue";

        Regex expression = new Regex(string.Format("$[{0}]$test$[{1}]$", value1, value2));
        expression.Match(input);
```

you will receiv a Regex that looks like:
$[firstValue]$test$[secondValue]$

Did I understood your question right?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with

```
Regex.Replace Method (String, String, MatchEvaluator)
```

See the docs on msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx)

From the documentation

> evaluator
>   Type: System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator
>   A custom method that examines each match and returns either the original matched string or a replacement string

So you can define the replacement dependent of the matched pattern and replace `[ABCD]` with something different that `[xyz]`

Comment: but first of all i want to validate the pattern like it may be a case i got a pattern like something $[ABCD test[xyz]$ which a invalid pattern because it is missing the "]"

Comment: Then you need to explain your pattern more, what can ABCD be? 4 chars in length? only letters? ... ?. what is with "test", "xyz"? But please do this in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a simple RegEx `\[\w*\]` and use [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) method of RegEx class

Example:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[\w*\]");
regex.Replace("$[ABCD]$test$[xyz]$", "replacement string");
```